# Prove that for every $0<A<B<\infty$: $\left|\int_{A}^{B}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right| \le \frac{A}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Prove that for every $0<A<B<\infty$: $$\left|\int_{A}^{B}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right|  \le  \frac{A}{2}.$$

I tried Taylor expansion : $\sin(x) = x +O(x)$, then I said $O(x)\le \frac{x}{2}$, but it didn't work!

Comment: Taylor expansion would actually tell you that $\sin x =x+O(x^3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may re-write your integral as
$$
\operatorname{Si}(B) - \operatorname{Si}(A) = \text{f}(A)\cos A + \text{g}(A)\sin A - \text{f}(B)\cos B - \text{g}(B)\sin B,
$$
using the notation in http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.ii and http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.iii. Now
$$
0 \le \text{f}(x) \le \frac{1}{x},\quad 0 \le \text{g}(x) \le \frac{1}{{x^2 }}
$$
for any $x>0$ (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.ii). Thus,
$$
\left| {\operatorname{Si}(B) - \operatorname{Si}(A)} \right| \le \frac{2}{A}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{A}} \right)
$$
for any $0<A<B$. This bound is particularly useful for large $A$.

Answer (score 4):

The claim is **wrong**. Note that the sinc function is continuous at $0$. When $A=0.000001$ and $B=\pi$ we therefore have
$$\int_A^\pi{\sin x\over x}\>dx\approx\int_0^\pi{\sin x\over x}\>dx\approx1.85194\ ,$$
and here the RHS is certainly $>{A\over2}$.